# Customizing the destination after user activates the account

Tags: craft3, users, registration

I would like to ask about activation e-mail which is sent to new user.

Once the user clicks the link, it redirects to homepage.
Is it possible to change the destination?
I would rather like to make it to login page.

Answer (score 1):

Craft support desk helped me, so I would like to share it.

The destination can be set with this. Add it on your `general.php`.

```
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'users/login',
```

Please be sure to change `'users/login'` to the destination you want to set.

If it does not works, add this;

```
'verifyEmailSuccessPath' => 'users/login'
```